# How to finish a Sidekiq job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Say I have a worker class that looks like this:

```
class BuilderWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(order_id)
    if(order_id == 5)
      # How can I finish the job here? Say I want to finish it with a status of FAIL or COMPLETE.
    end
  end
end
```

I am looking for a way to finish a job from the Worker class, and when finished give it the status of FAILED. The finish should be quiet, (not raising an exception)

Comment: do you want to raise an exception if order_id is 5? or simply quitely end the job?  what if order_id!=5 - what do you expect to happen then?

Comment: Actually the condition is more complicated than that, I just put that to simplify. The main thing is that I want to log something into my DB given some conditions and finish the job SILENTLY with a FAIL status (I have another worker which keeps checking job status). If that condition doesn't happen, I want the job to continue normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Sidekiq there are only two job results:

- success - a job returns from the perform method without error
- failure - a job raises an error, going onto the retry queue to be retried in the future

Your complicated scenario is called application logic and Sidekiq cannot provide it.  It is up to you to write that logic.